# Converting a saved photo into a WritableBitmap in WinRT

Tags: image-processing, windows-runtime

I have taken a photo and saved it, but I need to do image processing on it.  I tried using the following code, but `WritableBitmap` does not accept a bitmap, it needs a stream.

var writeableBitmap = new WritableBitmap(bitmap);

Here is the code:

```
CameraCaptureUI cam = new CameraCaptureUI();
var capturedImage = await cam.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
if (capturedImage != null)
{
    var img = new BitmapImage();
    img.SetSource(await capturedImage.OpenReadAsync());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick - You need to use the OpenAsync instead.

```
 var dialog = new CameraCaptureUI();
            var file = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
            if (file != null)
            {
                var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
                var img = new BitmapImage();
                img.SetSource(stream);
                AccountPictureImage.Source = img;
            }
```